# Cannot create JPQL query for bridge table in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpql

I use JPQL in some of Repository method in Java and Kotlin apps and can join multiple tables without any problem.

However, I needed to create a JPQL query for a bridge table that is automatically created by Hibernate and for this reason there is no entity class for this auto-generated bridge entity.

Here is related JPQL clause that I try to create. As there is no RolePermission entity, I cannot use it in my query:

```
@Query(
    """
        SELECT p.id, p.name FROM Permission p
        LEFT JOIN RolePermission rp on p.id = rp.permissionId
        LEFT JOIN Role r on rp.roleId = r.id
    """
)
fun GetAllPermissions(): List<Permission>
```

Here are related entity classes:

```
@Table(name = "role")
data class Role(

    val name: String,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "role_permission",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    )
    val permissions: MutableSet<Permission> = mutableSetOf()

) : AbstractAuditing()
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
data class Permission(

    val name: String

) : AbstractAuditing()
```

So, how can I create JPQL clause without changing entity classes and using native Query? Is it possible using JPQL?

I thought using something like `Role.permissions`, but still cannot acess bridge table fields :(